# I get an error whenever I try to connect database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, dataset

i've got an Access db with one table called "users" with one row:

**ID-username--password---admin---email--------------age---firstname--lastname**
 1---ido_doron---123456-------True-----my@email.com---20-----Ido-----------Doron

Now, I tried to create a public function that will check whether user is logged in, and whether he's an admin or an user:

```
public static string CheckLoginStatus()
{
    string username = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["username"];
    string password = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["password"];

    if (username == "" || password == "")
        return "failure";
    else
    {
        DataRow row = DBAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "';").Tables[0].Rows[0];
        if (row["password"] == password)
        {
            if (row["admin"] == "True")
            {
                return "admin";
            }
            else
            {
                return "user";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return ("no");
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I use this function, I get an error: "*There is no row at position 0.*"

I am adding the function that suppose to connect the database ("*GetDataSet()*"):

```
public static DataSet GetDataSet(string sqlStr)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnString());
    OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
    dbCmd.Connection = con;
    dbCmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCmd);
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Table1");
    return ds;
}
```

Do you know why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused this error, but I have recreated the function and now it works:

```
public static string CheckLoginStatus()
{
    string username = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["username"];
    string password = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["password"];
    if (username == "" || password == "")
        return "no";
    else if (DBAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "';").Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        DataRow row = DBAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "';").Tables[0].Rows[0];
        if (row["password"].ToString() == password)
        {
            if (row["admin"].ToString() == "True")
                return "admin";
            else
                return "user";
        }
        else
            return "no";
    }
    else
        return "no";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is this line:

```
DataRow row = DBAccess.GetDataSet(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "';").Tables[0].Rows[0];
```

You're assuming a table will be returned with at least one row in it.

If the `username` doesn't exist in the table, then nothing will be returned.

Temporarily, insert something like

```
var data = DBAccess.GetDataSet(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "';").Tables[0];
```

Place a breakpoint on that line of code, then step through and make sure that `data` has a table with the record you're expecting to find.

Comment: I know... But this query doesn't suppose to return 0 rows. Session["username"] = "ido_doron" - and therefore it suppose to return at least one row

Comment: both of the sessions return the same values found in the database table. I don't understand why the query returns zero rows.

Comment: @IdoDoron Have you tried temporarily hard-coding `... WHERE username='ido_doron'` to see if that makes a difference? (By the way, you really should be using a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

Modify below line

DataRow row = DBAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" + username + "';").Tables[0].Rows[0];

Check the number of rows in datatable before accessing data. If count is zero, it means your query did not return any record.